# Смена атрибутов

Tags: jquery

Есть какие-то блоки и какие-то атрибуты, допустим вот так:

```
<div class="one" data-newclass="one-new"></div>
<div class="red" data-newclass="blue-green"></div>
...
```

Нужно при нажатии кнопки, заменить у всех блоков содержимое `class` на `data-newclass`, а после повторного нажатия вернуть как было.

Идея есть, но мне кажется что она слишком глупая.

```js
$('input').on('click', function() {
  $('.list div').each(function(){
    var attr1 = $(this).attr('class'),
        attr2 = $(this).data('newclass');
    $(this).attr('class',attr2);
    $(this).data('newclass',attr1);
  });
});
```

```css
.list div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.one {
  background: #111;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.one-new {
  background: #111;
}
.one-new::after {
  content: '1';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
.blue-green {
  background: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
  <div class="one" data-newclass="one-new"></div>
  <div class="red" data-newclass="blue-green"></div>
  <div class="one" data-newclass="one-new"></div>
  <div class="red" data-newclass="blue-green"></div>
  <div class="one" data-newclass="one-new"></div>
  <div class="red" data-newclass="blue-green"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="click" />
```

Comment: вы хотите помудрить там, где простое решение уже реализовано? не надо с этим кодом более ничего делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого в jQuery есть метод [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

**UPD:** Прошу прощения, не сразу понял суть вопроса. Тогда либо так, как вы написали, либо можно сделать самому обработчик, например:

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){

  $.fn.toggleDataClass = function(dataAttr) {
      var newClass = $(this).attr(dataAttr);
      if ( $(this).hasClass( newClass ) ) { 
        $(this).removeClass( newClass );
      } else {
        $(this).addClass( newClass );
      }
      return this;
    };

  $('input').on('click', function() {
    $(".one").toggleDataClass("data-newclass");
    $(".red").toggleDataClass("data-newclass");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.list div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.one {
  background: #111;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.one-new {
  background: #111;
}
.one-new::after {
  content: '1';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
.blue-green {
  background: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="one" data-newclass="one-new"></div>
  <div class="red" data-newclass="blue-green"></div>
  <div class="one" data-newclass="one-new"></div>
  <div class="red" data-newclass="blue-green"></div>
  <div class="one" data-newclass="one-new"></div>
  <div class="red" data-newclass="blue-green"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="click" />
```

Comment: Это пример. Задача с атрибутами, а не с классами.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 вы же классы меняете. Вот вам и говорят, что можно сделать `class="one"`, а также атрибут `data-newclass="one new-one"` а потом сделать вызов `$(this).toggleClass($(this).data('newclass'))`, тога старый класс уберется, новый останется. и потом они по кругу так будут листаться.

Comment: @teran, это я знаю, а как получить такое же но с любыми другими атрибутами. Вопрос-то конкретно по атрибутам, не классам.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Если в ваш пример атрибут `class`  попал случайно, то вы привели плохой пример, и переформулируйте его так, чтобы не было неоднозначностей.

Comment: @teran, я специально пример представил таким, чтобы видно было принцип работы. Не думал что фраза "какие-то атрибуты, допустим вот так:" имеет ввиду классы.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 я вам уже написал, что ваше решение - простое и рабочее. не надо с ним далее мудрить.

Comment: @teran, значит я вас не понял, прошу прощение. Т.е. я вполне могу использовать тот вариант, что сам предложил?

Comment: @Kosmos, вопрос не по теме, что даёт `$.fn`?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, некое пространство имен jQuery, которое позволяет делать ряд вещей, например, писать собственные плагины, которые потом можно вызывать через $(selector).myOwnPlugin() или же узнать версию jQuery - $.fn.jquery (вернет версию подключенной библиотеки)

Подробнее - http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/what-does-fn-mean-in-jquery.html и https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/